# DjangoRestFramework Serializer как получить нужное значение

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Из модели получаю дату data_end. Мне нужно сравнить её с сегодняшней датой и вывести дату из модели, если она больше сегодняшней. В другом случае не выводить это поле. Мне нужно это в сериализаторе делать?

serializers.py

```
 class StorageAccessSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = models.StorageAccess
            fields = ['date_end']
```

models.py

```
class StorageAccess(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Пользователь')
    ed_program = models.ForeignKey('EducationProgram', on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                   verbose_name='Образовательная программа')
    date_start = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата начала')
    date_end = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата окончания')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'доступ к программе'
        verbose_name_plural = 'доступы к программе'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} / {self.ed_program.title}'
```